# MySQL Workbench migration from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL : ERROR: Determine number of rows to copy: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, mysql-workbench, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate a database from SQL Server 2008 to MySQL using MySQL Workbench 5.2.46CE. Everything works fine until the copy of the data (step "Bulk Data Transfer) :

> Starting...
>  Prepare information for data copy...
>  Prepare
>   information for data copy done
>  Determine number of rows to
>   copy....
>  Counting number of rows in tables...
>   wbcopytables.exe --count-only --passwords-from-stdin
>   --odbc-source=Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=... ;User Id=... ;Password=... --table-file=...
>  ERROR: Determine
>   number of rows to copy: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType'
>   and 'str'
>  Failed

I don't really understand why I get this, so if any of you have an idea... :)
(PS : I started using SQL Server 2008 & MySQL Workbench today so I don't really know how they work)

**EDIT 2** - SQL Express Table DDL (updated)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[S_OCivilite](
    [OCIV_Id] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT N'',
    [OCIV_Code_Pan] [nvarchar](3) NOT N'',
    [OCIV_Intitule_Pan] [nvarchar](35) NOT N'',
    [OCIV_DateModif_Pd] [datetime] NOT N'',
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OCIV_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OCIV_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_OCIV_Code_Pan] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [OCIV_Code_Pan] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: To me it sounds more like a bug. You should file a bug report for it http://bugs.mysql.com

Answer (score 1):

When moving from one DB to another you will always run into datatype conversion hurdles. In a nutshell you need to understand what table structures are in your source DB and how those map to the same structures in the target DB.All these SQL Databases support or should support ANSI SQL, the collective common aspect of SQL, however each DB vendor has procedural extensions and DDL that makes cross conversion interesting.

So reading your question you do not have SQL Server 2008, but SQL Express which is a "lite" version of SQL Server. Your error is saying that in reading a table to get the row counts it has found a datatype or an unsupported ddl statement and can't handle the typecasting.

I use MySQL workbench, but have not tried to migrate a full DB. You should look for settings that relax the typecasting or send everything into MySQL as a varchar and then have a subsequent ETL process correctly process and typecast the data. Or do a table at a time until you understand what it is truly complaining about.

If you can post the records or record it is complaining about or the table DDL from SQLExpress that would really help.

EDIT 1: Response to SQL DDL edit

I would first off suspect the Identity column in SQL Server. The MySQL corresponding Datatype should be AUTO_INCREMENT . You need to find the logs for Bulk loader. You should be able to set the level of logging and actually see what it is complaining about.

Comment: During the importation process, there's not a lot of options, so I don't think I can tell him to cast everything as a varchar (maybe by modifying the python scripts that do all the work, but I don't know python ^^)... I looked in SQL Server Management Studio to change database's options but didn't find anything relevant...

I've tried to migrate a few tables alone and I always get the errors (I thought it could be a problem with NULL values, but event tables without any NULL value send an error..).

Comment: Here is an example of a table from SQL Management Studio :

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[S_OCivilite](
[OCIV_Id] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
[OCIV_Code_Pan] [nvarchar](3) NOT NULL,
[OCIV_Intitule_Pan] [nvarchar](35) NOT NULL,
[OCIV_DateModif_Pd] [datetime] NOT NULL)

Comment: I only found 1 log file (user/AppData/Roaming/MySQL/Workbench/log) but I don't think it will help since there's not more informations : http://pastebin.com/cwJCRTs7 . 

Workbench correctly creates the new table in the MySQL database, then tries to count the number of rows and... fails :( 

I looked in Workbench settings but didn't find anyhting concerning the logs (there's not a lot of things in their settings).

Comment: If it is not your DDL then it has to be the data itself. What does the corresponding table definition in MySQL look like? How did it handle the Identity column? Is OCIV_Id in MySQL an AUTO_INCREMENT fieldtype?

Comment: Here is the MySQL DDL : 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `S_OCivilite` ( 
  `OCIV_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `OCIV_Code_Pan` varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
  `OCIV_Intitule_Pan` varchar(70) NOT NULL, 
  `OCIV_DateModif_Pd` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`OCIV_Id`), 
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_OCIV_Code_Pan` (`OCIV_Code_Pan`) 
) . Everything seems to be ok, Workbench does a good job on this part

Comment: 2 things. a timestamp and datetime datatypes are different and are handled differently by the DB storage engine. Is OCIV_DateModif_pd just the date something was modified? If so you might change the timestamp to a datetime. That may be the problem. The other thing is in your SQL Server DDL you don't specify a PK or Unique Key such as the MySQL table. If the Constraints are not identical between the two tables they will not store data the same way and may have what your MySQL table would see as a duplicate PK.

Comment: I tried changing the timestamp to a datetime ( `OCIV_DateModif_Pd` DATETIME NULL ), and removed the unique key (my mistake, on the SQL DDL I didn't copy the PK line... Just saw that... I'm gonna edit my first post, sorry ^^'), and always the same error... I tried another software (SQL Script Builder) that recreate everything except FK, I'm going to try to go with that... Thanks for your help anyway !

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution on this?? I am looking to perform the same process here and I am getting stuck with the same error.